# Trigonometric wizardry with the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to understand the first proof of the functional equation in Titchmarsh's famous book on the Zeta function (as edited by Heath-Brown), and I'm stuck.

This is because the author claims that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(y)}{y^{1+s}} dy = -Γ(-s) \cdot \sin\left( \frac{πy}{2} \right).
$$
For some reason, I'm too stupid to prove this identity. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume the argument of the sine has $s$ in it instead of $y$. You could apply Ramanujan's Master Theorem (this integral is of Mellin type).

Comment: The integral converges for $-1 < \operatorname {Re} s < 1$ but converges absolutely only for $0 < \operatorname {Re} s < 1$. If we want to use self-adjointness of the Laplace transform, we can either do it for $0 < \operatorname {Re} s < 1$ and then invoke an analytic continuation argument or prove that the improper Riemann integrals in the iterated integral $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \sin(y_1) y_2^s e^{-y_1 y_2} dy_1 dy_2$ are interchangeable for $-1 < \operatorname {Re} s < 1$. Applying the Mellin inversion theorem together with the residue theorem is not completely straightforward either.

Answer (score 2):

Start with
$$I(y)=\int\frac{e^{iy}}{y^{1+s}}\,dy=-y^{-s} E_{s+1}(-i y)$$ Assuming $s>0$, $I(\infty)=0$ and $I(0)=-(-i)^s \Gamma (-s,0)$. So
$$\int y^{-(1+s)} \sin (y)\,dy=\Im\left(-i)^s\right)\Gamma (-s,0)=-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)\,\Gamma (-s,0)=-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right)\,\Gamma (-s)$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(y)}{y^{1+s}}\,dy$ is convergent for any $s> -1$ by Dirichlet's criterion. The Laplace transform of $\sin(y)$ is $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ and the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{y^{1+s}}$ is $\frac{t^s}{\Gamma(s+1)}$, so
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(y)}{y^{1+s}}\,dy = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^s}{t^2+1}\,dt \stackrel{\frac{1}{1+t^2}\mapsto u}{=}\frac{1}{2\,\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{\frac{s-1}{2}}u^{-\frac{s+1}{2}}\,du$$
and by Euler's Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function the RHS equals
$$ \frac{1}{2\,\Gamma(s+1)}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1+s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\Gamma(s+1)\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}=-\Gamma(-s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right). $$

Comment: Your reputation makes you a half  devil :-).